# Confusion with pointers and objects (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c

The author wrote that whenever the value of `point` changes the value of `myRect's origin` will change as well, but I don't understand how turning `origin` into an object fixes it. What's the difference between creating an object and a pointer?

Fixed `setOrigin` method:

```
-(void) setOrigin:(XYpoint *)pt {
    if (! origin)
        origin = [[XYpoint alloc] init];

    origin.x = pt.x;
    origin.y = pt.y;
}
```

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYPoint : NSObject 
@property int x, y;

@end
```

---

```
#import "XYpoint.h"

@implementation XYPoint
@synthesize x, y;

@end
```

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class XYPoint;
@interface Rectangle: NSObject

-(void) setOrigin: (XYPoint *) pt; 

@end
```

---

```
#import "Rectangle.h"
#import "XYpoint.h"

@implementation Rectangle {
    XYPoint *origin;
}

-(void) setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt {
    origin = pt;
}

@end
```

---

```
#import "XYpoint.h"
#import "Rectangle.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Rectangle *myRect = [[Rectangle alloc] init];
        XYpoint *point = [[XYpoint alloc] init];

        point.x = 3;
        point.y = 8;

        [myRect setOrigin: point];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you're confused... This entire thing is implemented with objects (and fairly well, at that).  Pointers merely ***point to*** the object. What's the alternative, a struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XYPoint *origin;` is a pointer to the object that contains `x` and `y`. In this case in particular you have two references that point to the same exact object. `myRect.origin` and `point` point to the same `XYpoint` object. What this means is if you change the value of `x` or `y` by either means (`myRect.origin.x = 1` or `point.x = 1`), the updated `x` and `y` will be when accessed either way (`myRect.origin` or `point`).